# Column div layout not working in all browsers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple column layout where mainContent and rightContent is in the same "row". Instead of using CSS I want to set styles in JavaScript.

This is what I have http://jsfiddle.net/tKt5J/2/ .

```
var mainContent = document.getElementById('mainContent');
var rightContent = document.getElementById('rightContent');
mainContent.style.width = "70%";
mainContent.style.styleFloat = "left";
rightContent.style.width = "20%";
rightContent.style.styleFloat = "left";
```

For some reason this works in IE 11 but not in other browsers (such as Chrome 33). How can I make it work across browsers?

Comment: By using standard way of doing things ?

Comment: @Virus721 rather not say anything if you don't want to answer.

Comment: @Dumisani This is what comments are for, rocket scientist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tKt5J/7/)

Use `cssFloat` instead of `styleFloat`:

```
mainContent.style.cssFloat = "left";
rightContent.style.cssFloat = "left";
```

According to the note in [MDN `float` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float),

> If you're referring to this property from JavaScript as a member of
>   the `element.style` object, you must spell it as `cssFloat`. Also note
>   that Internet Explorer versions 8 and older spelled this `styleFloat`.
>   This is an exception to the rule that the name of the DOM member is
>   the camel-case name of the dash-separated CSS name (and is due to the
>   fact that "float" is a reserved word in JavaScript, as with the need
>   to escape "class" as "className" and escape 's "for" as
>   "htmlFor").

Answer (score 0):

I think you want float vs. styleFloat:

```
mainContent.style.float = "left";
rightContent.style.float = "left";
```

Comment: For me this does not work in Firefox 27. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/tKt5J/6/ .

Comment: then you should use jquery because $('#mainContent').css({float: 'left'}); will apply the most basic and w3c compliant style property.

Comment: I wish not to use any external libraries.